# How do I link my app to the App Store developer page?

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios, app-store

I have tried and tried but I cannot seem to make this work. I am just trying to get my app to link to my developer page in the App Store (so open the App Store application on the iPhone, obviously).

There has to be something I am missing. Perhaps some format issue? Can anyone help me out?

My apologies. But I have looked at all the zillion other questions and a good portion of them were old and were implementing the same method

```
 NSString *iTunesLink = @"http://phobos.apple.com/WebObjects/MZStore.woa/wa/viewSoftware?id=284417350&mt=8";
[[UIApplication sharedApplication] openURL:[NSURL URLWithString:iTunesLink]];
```

does not work. It just opens itunes app (which tells me it can't complete request), not the app store app

Here is the real code i'm using

```
- (IBAction)developer:(id)sender {
NSString *iTunesLink = @"http://itunes.apple.com/us/artist/esoteric-development/id416932838";

[[UIApplication sharedApplication] openURL:[NSURL URLWithString:iTunesLink]];
}
```

Comment: Besides not providing any detail about *your specific problem*, you also haven't told us what you've "tried and tried", nor if you've taken a look at the zillion other related (exact) questions already on Stack Overflow.

Comment: My apologies. But I have looked at all the zillion other questions and a good portion of them were old and were implementing the same method    NSString *iTunesLink = @"http://phobos.apple.com/WebObjects/MZStore.woa/wa/viewSoftware?id=284417350&mt=8";

[[UIApplication sharedApplication] openURL:[NSURL URLWithString:iTunesLink]];                                              does not work. It just opens itunes app (which tells me it can't complete request), not the app store app

Comment: I suggest posting the code that you've already tried. You can edit your existing question to add it at the bottom. Make sure that you select the entire block and use the code formatting button on the toolbar (the one with the curly braces `{}`) so that it gets syntax highlighting!

Comment: The **real** code. Because the snippet works perfectly.

Comment: I edited the post to include the actual code

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Based on the section *Company Name examples* of the [QA 1633](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#qa/qa2008/qa1633.html), to link to the applications of your company, you simply need to link to:

http://itunes.com/apps/your_company_name

For example, for MacMation's apps =>    http://itunes.com/apps/macmation
or in code:

```
[[UIApplication sharedApplication] openURL:[NSURL URLWithString:@"http://itunes.com/apps/macmation"]];
```

I tested with this url and a few others (like Sega, friends' companies...). It works.
After a few redirections, you end up on the App Store application, listing all the applications of your company.

With your company name, don't forget to remove the dash, to end up with: `http://itunes.com/apps/esotericdevelopment`

---

**Follow-up:**
The link you get from right-clicking the company name in iTunes works on Safari (on a Mac), but doesn't work on Mobile Safari, with the same error that you were describing: ends up on iTunes app with an error message.

Same broken behavior when opened from your app with this code:

```
[[UIApplication sharedApplication] openURL:[NSURL URLWithString:@"http://itunes.apple.com/fr/artist/macmation/id355312244"]];
```

(Tested on an iPhone on iOS 4.1)

Comment: So i might be outta luck here huh?

Comment: I just tried your method actually and it does work. It redirects to safari, then to itunes app, then finally to app store app. Thanks a bunch.

Answer (score 3):

Here's what worked for me using iOS6 and tested on iPhone5 and iPad:

```
- (IBAction)ourOtherAppsPressed:(id)sender {
    NSString *iTunesLink = @"itms-apps://itunes.apple.com/us/artist/samer-maaliki/id615908604";

    [[UIApplication sharedApplication] openURL:[NSURL URLWithString:iTunesLink]];
}
```

This goes straight to the App Store app rather than iTunes or Safari.

Answer (score 2):

One thing I would change above is to use the `itms://` scheme instead of `http://`. Using `http://` will cause it to launch Safari and redirect to the iTunes store app. Using `itms://` will take you there directly.

Answer (score 0):

You should read [Technical Q&A QA1629](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#qa/qa2008/qa1629.html) and [Technical Q&A QA1633](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#qa/qa2008/qa1633.html).

Comment: this is what I was using. But it opens up the itunes app, not the app store app for some reason. The itunes app just tells me it can't complete the request.

Comment: @Storms. The code from your edited question opens the page for Remote in the iPad app store. Maybe you should post your real code.

Answer (score 0):

I think you are trying to send the user to your app store link, is yes, then its simple, open that link in safari. 
 eg.[[UIApplication sharedApplication] openURL:[NSURL URLWithString: @"http://www.google.co.in"]];

If not, please elaborate.

Comment: yeah thats right. but when i try it opens the itunes app not the app store app. The itunes app tells me it can't complete the request.

Comment: try this                                                   NSString *iTunesLink = @"http://itunes.apple.com/app/remote/id284417350?mt=8";
 [[UIApplication sharedApplication] openURL:[NSURL URLWithString:iTunesLink]];